# App Crash while parsing data from one fragment to another android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[image: Crash]
[image: Data]
[image: retriveData]

I don't know what happened in this code. Anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

I am trying to parce data from one fragment to another fragment using parcelable, but my app crashed while fetching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you passed some data in next fragment (B), then you perform some operation in fragment (B), so if the data is null application was crashed.
so check your next fragment (B) and maintain null check condition.
if already maintained then you can share code where you fetching data in next fragment.

EDITED :-

```
if (arguments != null) {
        data = requireArguments().getParcelable<GetShopsResponse.Data.Shop::class.java>("shopData")
    }
```

note :- check every data with null check , if any data is null then app will crash.

Comment: [Code](https://codeshare.io/AdlkZe)

Comment: Please check the code link I shared with you.

Comment: okay , let me check @Lovish

Comment: Can you checked it??

Comment: arguments.getParcelable<GetShopsResponse.Data.Shop::class.java>("shopData")

Comment: I already do this but it cant work.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that you are calling your hashcode method on a null object which is -`GetShopsResponse.Data.Shop.Attachment` you should nullcheck it first like this:

```
GetShopsResponse.Data.Shop.Attachment?.hascode()
```

Comment: Is this code to be placed in the fetching or putting data screens?

Comment: everywhere you are calling hashcode function you have to see whether it is a nullable or not if it's nullable then null check is required

Comment: But I am not using hashcode anywhere. Can you see my code in anydesk?

Comment: The Error says that you are calling hashcode() method on something which is null so in your case it is (GetShopsResponse.Data.Shop.Attachment) so wherever you are calling hashcode in the GetShopsResponse class you have to check that it should not be null by adding a null check like this (GetShopsResponse.Data.Shop.Attachment)?.hashcode() wherever you are using hashcode method

Comment: yeah sure i can see your code

Comment: 342498244 its my anydesk id please join.